# Удаление метки с опечаткой

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Метка [androdi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/androdi/info) явно создана по ошибке, надо её удалить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov не знал об этом. Невнимательно, видать, инструкцию читал.

Comment: А можно сделать синоним и жить дальше без опасений, что кто-то опечатается ещё раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По метке 0 вопросов, поэтому она автоматически удалится через 6 месяцев. Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> на некоторых сайтах новые метки будут автоматически блокироваться и удаляться из системы, если за 6 месяцев их не используют хотя бы ещё один раз;

Comment: В полночь она удалится. За шесть месяцев - это если бы она осталась на вопросе.

Comment: Через сутки же, а не 6 месяцев?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну завтра и глянем, может и так. А можете написать свой ответ с ссылкой на срок о сутках. Если выпилить метку, то она, насколько я видел, дольше чем сутки жила.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, удалилась. Может, напишите тогда ответом, желательно с ссылками. Так как про сутки я не знал.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ну ответ я написал, но ссылок у меня нет.

Answer (score 1):

Неиспользуемые метки автоматически удаляются в течение суток.